# Can I save a postback status and restore it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-3.5

Suppose that, after a click on a `asp:button`, I'd like to store the actual "view", with selected value for each controllers, like asp:checkbox, or input inserted by users on inputbox.

Than, I change page, with a link such as "back to the previous page". I'd like so "restore" the old actual form, before leaving it.

Is it possible with .NET? Or I need to implements all controls in variables and put them in session?

Comment: Is this ASP.NET or ASP.NET-MVC?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: Yeah, I mean somethings different from this! I have tons of controls to store/restore :)

Comment: You can actually persist the viewstate to disk and restore it.  It's pretty hacky of a solution, but it would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need sessions to do this. Just make use of JavaScript.

Consider you have two pages Page1.aspx and Page2.aspx.
You have textboxes , checkboxes , radiobuttons on Page1.aspx and you have a button "Submit". By clicking the button it takes to Page2.aspx.

Just have a button "Back to Previous Page" on Page2.aspx , which on clicking takes you to Page1.aspx with all those values still being there. To do this, Add this line on your Page2.aspx page_load event

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 btnBackButton.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:window.history.go(-1);return false;");
}
```

Comment: Wooowww...very nice tricks :) I also should put (-2) and manage it very well! Thank you! P.S. Do you know any browser where this doesnt works?  Maybe because history it is not supported, or because turning back it doesnt store old data... Just curios...

Comment: Glad it helped you out. It works in almost all browsers (tested in safari and conqueror for ya ;) ) ., This doesn't work when Javascript is disabled.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways how you can persist or pass values between ASP.NET pages.

Have a look [here](http://How%20to%3a%20Pass%20Values%20Between%20ASP.NET%20Web%20Pages) for more informations.

Because you've mentioned that you have "tons" of controls to store and restore, i've tried to find a way to automatize this process.

Here's my approach which uses Session as storage to persist all controls' values of type [`IPostBackDataHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.ipostbackdatahandler.aspx). Not really tested but hopefully helpful anyway.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public class FormStorage
{
    private System.Web.UI.Page _page = null;

    public Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, String>> storage
    {
        get { return (Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, String>>)_page.Session["FormStorage"]; }
        set { _page.Session["FormStorage"] = value; }
    }

    public FormStorage(System.Web.UI.Page page)
    {
        _page = page;
        initHandler();
        if (this.storage == null)
        {
            this.storage = new Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, String>>();
        }
        if(!this.storage.ContainsKey(_page.Request.Path))
            this.storage.Add(_page.Request.Path, new Dictionary<String, String>());
    }

    private void initHandler()
    {
        _page.Init += Init;
        _page.Load += Load;
    }

    private void Init(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        loadForm();
    }

    private void Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        saveForm();
    }

    private void loadForm()
    {
        var pageStorage = storage[_page.Request.Path];
        var e = pageStorage.GetEnumerator();
        while (e.MoveNext())
        {
            loadControl(e.Current.Key, e.Current.Value);
        }
    }

    private void loadControl(String ID, String value)
    {
        Control control = findControlRecursively(_page, ID);
        if (control != null)
        {
            setControlValue(control, value);
        }
    }

    private void setControlValue(Control control, String value)
    {
        if (control is ITextControl)
        {
            ITextControl txt = (ITextControl)control;
            txt.Text = value == null ? "" : value;
        }
        else if (control is ICheckBoxControl)
        {
            ICheckBoxControl chk = (ICheckBoxControl)control;
            chk.Checked = value != null;
        }
        else if (control is ListControl)
        {
            ListControl ddl = (ListControl)control;
            if (value == null)
                ddl.SelectedIndex = -1;
            else
                ddl.SelectedValue = value;
        }
    }

    public void saveForm()
    {
        saveControlRecursively(this._page);
    }

    private void saveControlRecursively(Control rootControl)
    {
        if (rootControl is IPostBackDataHandler)
        {
            var postBackData = _page.Request.Form[rootControl.ID];
            storage[_page.Request.Path][rootControl.ID] = postBackData;
        }

        if (rootControl.HasControls())
            foreach (Control subControl in rootControl.Controls)
                saveControlRecursively(subControl);
    }

    private static Control findControlRecursively(Control rootControl, String idToFind)
    {
        if (rootControl.ID == idToFind)
            return rootControl;

        foreach (Control subControl in rootControl.Controls)
        {
            Control controlToReturn = findControlRecursively(subControl, idToFind);
            if (controlToReturn != null)
            {
                return controlToReturn;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here's an examplary implementation in a page that redirects to another page:

```
private FormStorage storage;

protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    storage = new FormStorage(this);
}

protected void BtnRedirect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("RedirectForm.aspx");
}
```

Note that it loads and saves implicitely on `Page_Load/Page_PreRender`. Therefor the `FormStorage` instance must be created in `Page_PreInit`.

If you want to change values after `Page_Load` programmatically, you need to call `storage.saveForm()` manually (for example in `Page_PreRender`) to ensure that these values are overridden, because `FormStorage` will auto-save all postback data in `Page_Load`.

**Edit**: The `history.go` approach of sh4nx0r is probably better since it's more scalable. My approach uses the Session and would not be appropriate for an internet-application with a huge amount of (possible) users.

One (small) advantage of mine is that it would work even when javascript is disabled. One larger advantage is that you can control to what page you want to redirect. You can even restore values across multiple redirects.

Comment: Thanks, maybe i'll use this to restore pages after the user visited some other pages (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10600566/is-it-possible-to-save-and-restore-a-complete-aspx-page). It seems to work fine in a small test website. I just removed the `SaveForm` in the load, because it does not save a restored page. I'll only save pages when I want it myself (after a search or something). Thanks!