# Is it possible to save and restore a complete aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iframe

Our customers have this requirement:

- A search page should be shown in a modal dialog (iframe) when the user clicks the search icon on a form
- The user can search, browse his search results, and select a record
- Now the modal dialog hidden and the user views the record
- When the user clicks search icon again, the modal dialog shows up again

Now the part for my question:

- When the user leaves the current page, and returns on the page after a few minutes and presses the search icon again to continue with his search, he should see the same page as where he left before.

I prefer to just save the complete page and restore it when the user wants to view the search page again. But I don't know if that is possible..

I don't really want to save all the search filters, and do the search again when the user goes to search page, because there are > 100 search filters and the search can take while also.

It is a hard requirement from the customer that he should be able to continue with his search, and should not start over again every time he goes to the search page again.

Thanks for all suggestions on this.

Comment: Isn't it what browser back button is supposed to do? I would suggest you make the form do a GET and use what LesterDove has suggested.

Comment: I don't got the feeling that you understand my question. The idea is: When user clicks on a search icon, he gets a modal dialog with a search page. When he selects a record in the search results, the modal dialog closes and the user views the record. When the user clicks the search icon again, the modal dialog is shown again. When the user goes to another page, and returns here, he wants to see the same search page when he clicks the view button. This has got nothing to do with going back and forward.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you could use .NET's @OutputCache page declaration with the VaryByParam attribute set (if the search params are pass through the querystring, at least.)

Comment: The idea is same, but would suggest to wrap this functionality in a user control, so that if any user specific information in the page will not be cached and displayed to other user.

Comment: Hm, I got no querystring parameters. The modal dialog is a search form with a lot of filters for the user to set (also too much for a querystring) and that form also shows the search results. When the user selects a record from the search results, the modal dialog hides and the record is shown. When the user clicks the search icon again, the modal dialog shows up again.

Comment: Also, its no caching issue. When the user opens the modal dialog to search, I want to manually restore the page at the same state where he left it the last time.

Comment: I understand.  You could try to use ViewState to restore the state of all those search controls in one fell swoop.

Answer (score 0):

I would come up with some sort of custom cache mechanism to store search results on the server.  when the user submits a search, results are stored in the cache and a key is returned to the page.  then when the user clicks the button to re-view the results, retrieve the results from the server using the key.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you save the search results to a session or viewstate variable?

If I was in your position (and could not save the search results to a session variable) I would:

1. Make the modal dialog its own page.
2. [Download the page](http://www.csharp-examples.net/download-files/) on the server (server connects to the modal dialog page and downloads the contents).
3. Store the downloaded page somewhere (probably the session, but maybe the database or in the file system).
4. Add an [iFrame](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) to the modal dialog (make sure you add the name field or it will not work in FF).
5. Set the source of the iFrame in the modal dialog to the saved search results.

It should be noted that this solution will have issues if the search results use server side, browser dependent controls (controls which return different HTML based on the browser type indicated at the server).

If you want, the iFrame can be replaced with a div if you set the div's inner html to the inner html of the body tags on the saved page.

I believe there is also a feature built into ASP which will get the rendered text of a page, but I do not remember what it is called.